# How to wait async process from other class?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have two classes

Parser.cs:

```
....
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Flight>(e.Result);
};

client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
```

and Main.cs:

```
...
var p = new Parser();
p.Parse();

someMethod(p.Result);
```

How can i run **someMethod** when DownloadStringAsync from Parser.cs is done?

Comment: You should with to the Task class and TPL.

Comment: Can you show the signatures of the `Parse()` and `DownloadStringAsync()` methods?

Comment: @NedStoyanov DownloadStringAsync() is a default method of System.Net.Webclient.

Parse: public void Parse()

Answer (score 2):

This is accomplished by using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

You can change your Parse method to:

```
Task<string> ParseAsync()
{
    return client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(uri));
}
```

Then your Main method:

```
var p = new Parser();
var parseTask = p.Parse();

//This will block the current thread until Result is available
someMethod(parseTask.Result);
```

or if you don't want to block current thread, you can use continuation:

```
var p = new Parser(); 
var parseTask = p.Parse(); 
parseTask.ContinueWith(task => someMethod(task.Result));
```

All this is assuming .Net 4.5.

Comment: Updated per proposition by [Isantipov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1990682/isantipov) Thank you for correcting me! :)